# Dynamically Populate a TreeView using 2 dimensional list or array's in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

I am trying to populate a Pre-Existing TreeView, with items from a two dimensional source such as a List> or an  array[,].

For example imagine I had a list as follows:

Sarah, john, Jill, bill

Sarah, Joe, Jill

Matt, Micheal, Sue, George

Matt, Micheal, Sue, George, Sam

In this example if a name exists on the left then that is that persons parent, and to the right represents their child.

I started writing the following code but got stuck:

```
 private TreeNode ParentChild(TreeNode node, string parent, string child)
    {
        if (!node.Nodes.ContainsKey(parent))
        {
            TreeNode p = new TreeNode(parent);
             p.Name = parent;
             node.Nodes.Add(p);
        }
        if (!node.Nodes[parent].Nodes.ContainsKey(child))
        {
            TreeNode c = new TreeNode(child);
            c.Name = child;
            node.Nodes[parent].Nodes.Add(child);
        }

  private TreeView addNode(List<List<string>> keys, TreeView tree, TreeView tree1)
    {


        for(int i=0; i<keys.Count;i++)
        {
            TreeNode top= new TreeNode();
            if(tree.Nodes.ContainsKey(keys[i][0]))
                 top= tree.Nodes[keys[i][0]];
            for( int j = 0; j<keys.Count-1; j++)
            {

                TreeNode a = ParentChild(top,keys[i][j],keys[i][j+1]);
            }
            tree.Nodes.Add(top);
        }


    }
```

Example of Nested List:
 public void example()
         {

```
       List<List<string>> example = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
        tmp.Add("Sarah");
        tmp.Add("John");
        tmp.Add("Jill");
        tmp.Add("Bill");
        example.Add(tmp);
        List<string> tmp2 = new List<string>();
        tmp2.Add("Sarah");
        tmp2.Add("Joe");
        tmp2.Add("Jill");
        example.Add(tmp2);
        List<string> tmp3 = new List<string>();
        tmp3.Add("Matt");
        tmp3.Add("Micheal");
        tmp3.Add("Sue");
        tmp3.Add("george");
        example.Add(tmp3);
        List<string> tmp4 = new List<string>();
        tmp3.Add("Matt");
        tmp3.Add("Micheal");
        tmp3.Add("Sue");
        tmp3.Add("George");
        tmp4.Add("Sam");
        example.Add(tmp4);
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of lists?

Comment: I am trying to create a TreeView from a multidimensional list, for this exercise I was using a nested list. But a 2D-Array could have been used as well.

Comment: post the code for the nested list..

Comment: i added an example at the bottom of the code above.